# How can i create the below attached template in html css bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am buidling an application and getting stucked with one of the blocker:

I want to create the template like below in html/css/bootstrap. 
[image]
Steps i'm following:

I created a card and will fetch and print the value from DB on these cards but i'm not sure how on clicking a submit would store my value in db or process it as a POST request to another page. Is there any possibility like forms can be used with cards?

I am creting my card using the below code:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Card Header and Footer</h2>
  <div class="card" >
    <div class="card-header" color="black" ><h1 style="display: inline;">hello</h1> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <h1 style="display: inline;">hello</h1></div>
    <div class="card-body">Content</div>
    <div class="card-footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I'm very new to front end if someone can just direct me how to do without pasting the actual code as well can help me upto some extent.**

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic layout for your problem. You can go and add additional classes to style the different columns width and layout.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form action="">
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="card" data-fareid="xyz123" data-price="15000" data-departure="22:10" data-arrival="23:25">
    <div class="card-header">Card header</h2></div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col"><img src="xyz.png"></div>
          <div class="col">22:10</div>
          <div class="col">01:15min</div>
          <div class="col">23:25</div>
          <div class="col">15.000</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">Card footer</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can i use these hardcoded values to be submitted as a post request. Can i use forms here on top of container class?

Comment: yes of course you can use forms with this page. you can think about providing the values of the selected fare in hidden form fields, or even in a data-attribute of that card, which you then can send back to the server or whatever you like (sorry, I'm only a front end developer, not the backend guy... :-D )
I have added some matching data-attributes to my sample